# CSS Rotation/Animation discrepancy in Browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a problem animating the rotation of some images in: MS Edge, IE and Safari.

In Chrome, Firefox and Opera the animation seems to work ok: Cards rotation shows both sides, and on hover the animation stops.

On MS Edge the animation flicks after few seconds, transform and z-index change between images has a discrepancy and it starts showing "the other side" during the rotation. --- On hover the animation stops, but on mouse-out after the animation returns the animation flicks again.

In IE, hover seems to be not working. I believe that here the problem is on the z-index not changing and showing the back image animation on top. On mouse out it makes weird half-cards images.

In Safari, it looks too weird and doesn't work at all.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

```html
<body>
  <style>
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .panel {
      width: 128px;
      height: 128px;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -o-transition: all .5s;
      -ms-transition: all .5s;
      -moz-transition: all .5s;
      -webkit-transition: all .5s;
      transition: all .5s;
    }
    
    .front {
      background-size: contain;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 3000;
      -webkit-animation: CardFlipFront 2.5s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: CardFlipFront 2.5s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: CardFlipFront 2.5s linear infinite;
      animation: CardFlipFront 2.5s linear infinite;
    }
    
    .back {
      background-size: contain;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      -webkit-animation: CardFlipBack 2.5s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: CardFlipBack 2.5s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: CardFlipBack 2.5s linear infinite;
      animation: CardFlipBack 2.5s linear infinite;
    }
    
    .panel:hover .front {
      z-index: 4000;
      transition: 0s;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -webkit-animation: none;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    
    .panel:hover .back {
      z-index: 4000;
      transition: 0s;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -webkit-animation: none;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    /* Animation Webkit  */
    
    @-webkit-keyframes CardFlipFront {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
      50% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes CardFlipBack {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      }
      50% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      }
    }
    /* Animation Mozila */
    
    @-moz-keyframes CardFlipFront {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
      50% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes CardFlipBack {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      }
      50% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      }
    }
    /* Animation MS */
    
    @keyframes CardFlipFront {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
      50% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
        transform: rotateY(0);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes CardFlipBack {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      }
      50% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 3000;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      }
    }
    
    #Card_1 .front {
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/128/128/abstract/3/Dummy-Text/');
    }
    
    #Card_1 .back {
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/128/128/animals/1/Dummy-Text/');
    }
    
    #Card_2 .front {
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/128/128/people/2/Dummy-Text/');
    }
    
    #Card_2 .back {
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/128/128/food/2/Dummy-Text/');
    }
    
    #Card_3 .front {
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/128/128/people/4/Dummy-Text/');
    }
    
    #Card_3 .back {
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/128/128/transport/3/Dummy-Text/');
    }
  </style>
  <div id="cards" align="center">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h1>Card 1</h1>
            <h2>Card Name</h2>
            <div id="Card_1" class="panel">
              <div class="front card"></div>
              <div class="back card"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h1>Card 2</h1>
            <h2>Card Name</h2>
            <div id="Card_2" class="panel">
              <div class="front card"></div>
              <div class="back card"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h1>Card 3</h1>
            <h2>Card Name</h2>
            <div id="Card_3" class="panel">
              <div class="front card"></div>
              <div class="back card"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvJxOE)

Comment: may be "pie.htc" will solve your problem with ie